# I want to fetch submitted gravityform entries into another gravityform (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Suppose I made form A and form B, I get a unique ID after submitting form A  after that, another person opened form B and he entered just a unique ID given by me and enter additional information and submit it, then he might see the name and email ID that I entered in form A.

Please guide me to do this, also tell me if there is any form plugin or gravityform addon for this.

Now, in this case, I am trying to fetch submitted entries from form A to form B by using a unique ID that I created. (for unique ID I have a plugin so no worries about it)